# C# .NET 4.0 WCF MessageSecurityException, "Security header is empty." when consuming a service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, soap

When using WCF and C# in a project I get an exception, MesssageSecurityException, with the message "Security header is empty.". Here follows the response (according to MS Service Trace Viewer):

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true"></wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action>_WHAT_I_DID_</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>_MSG_ID_OF_REQUEST_</wsa:RelatesTo>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
        _CORRECT_BODY_
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Indeed, the security header is "empty", but it is still correct accprding to the security header definition as far as I can tell.

I've also tried editing the bindings, but that doesn't seem to help as well. I also found a similar problem where enabling `EnableUnsecuredResponse` would help, but it doesn't here.

Here is the response according to SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
      <wsa:Action>_WHAT_I_DID_</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>_REQ_MSG_ID_</wsa:RelatesTo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      _CORRECT_BODY_
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

They are almost identical, except for how they close the security header. Which is interesting, but should not raise the exception?

I also found a [similar problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wcf/thread/bd244349-f3e0-4a07-93bb-b656590ad628) where the solution was to create a custom message encoder and strip the entire security header, although this would work it is an extra unneeded step. Is that the only way to do it with .Net and WCF? Can't WCF handle security headers without content?

EDIT:
Clarification of the issue, is writing an encoder which drops the security header the only way to recieve and parse SOAP-messages with empty security headers using WCF?

EDIT2: Adding part of conf:

```
    <binding name="NinjaBinding">
      <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
      authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="false"
      securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="false" allowInsecureTransport="true"
      keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy"
      messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature"
    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
      requireSecurityContextCancellation="false">
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap _IDENTICAL_TO_ABOVE_
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
```

As far as I know, its configure to allow practically everything?

Comment: What is security configuration of your client? Are you consuming WCF or non-WCF service? Whey is security header even included if it is empty? What security is used in request?

Comment: Security conf, basicly just `UserNameOverTransport` and https-transport binding, the rest should not matter according to ws-spec (and I've gone through every single App.config setting AFAIK). Non-WCF by SOAP. Why the header is included? I have no idea? But my client is just consuming the server. Security in req, same as conf. The question is really this: Do you have to write a custom message encoder or can you configure WCF in some way to drop the security header without implementing an encoder?

Comment: Do you mean you are using the Security Mode = Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential?

Comment: Security mode isn't applicable to httpsTransport as far as I know. BasicHttpBinding is one of the few which does. Or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Now I'm answering my own question since I've been able to elicit some kind of answer)

In short, **no you cannot use WCF "out of the box" (ie through *.config) with application servers which provide empty security headers in responses**. You have to implement an encoder which modifies messages to a format acceptable by the WCF-framework.

For more information read [this blog](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2010/04/01/WCF-Interoperability-and-Extensibility-Part-One.aspx) which contains a quite good walkthrough of the encoder and its applications. [This blog (another blog)](http://zianet.dk/blog/2011/01/10/removing-the-soap-mustunderstand-attribute-from-a-wcf-message/) also provides a code snippet capable of solving my issue, ie modifying the security header.

I wonder why MS and Oracle products never can co-exist peacefully :D

Comment: The question is if WS-Security specification allows this header to be empty. I didn't find clear answer for that.

Comment: Neither did I, but there is nothing which states that it **cannot** both be empty and contain a mustUnderstand attribute set to _true_.